# NOT IN/EXISTS em mais de uma tabela na mesma consulta

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

Eu tenho uma tabela de empregados e preciso extrair dela uma consulta de funcionários que não estejam cadastrados em nenhum dos cargos (**arquiteto, paisagista e gerente**).
A coluna **COD** de *empregado* é a chave primaria de todas as outras colunas dos cargos em tabelados.

**table empregado**

```
COD | NOME
1   | joão
2   | maria
3   | josé
4   | paulo
5   | pedro
```

**table: arquiteto**

```
COD | PROJETO
1     336B
```

**table: paisagista**

```
COD | PROJETO
3     1052
```

**table: gerente**

```
COD | PROJETO
4     450
```

Eu tentei usar a estratégia de aninhar as consultas me trazendo somente as pessoas cadastradas nos cargos e depois realizar um select com NOT IN, assim teria somente funcionários que não estejam nesses cargos

```
SELECT empregado.cod
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT arquiteto.cod)
```

Só que eu precisaria validar as 3 tabelas em uma única consulta. Alguém me sugere qual é a melhor estratégia para retornar os funcionários sem cargos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apesar da modelagem ser bem esquisita tente:

```
SELECT empregado.cod
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
      (SELECT cod FROM arquiteto WHERE empregado.cod = arquiteto.cod 
       UNION
       SELECT cod FROM paisagista WHERE empregado.cod = paisagista.cod
       UNION
       SELECT cod FROM gerente WHERE empregado.cod = gerente.cod)
```

ou

```
SELECT empregado.cod
WHERE NOT IN (SELECT cod FROM arquiteto
              UNION
              SELECT cod FROM paisagista
              UNION
              SELECT cod FROM gerente)
```

Comment: Olá, eu só fiz alguns ajustes aqui mas tua orientação deu certo sim. Concordo MUITO que a modelagem tá bizarra kk.

Comment: Ajustes: 
SELECT empregado.cod
FROM empregado
WHERE empregado.cod NOT IN (SELECT cod FROM ARQUITETO where empregado.cod = arquiteto.cod
UNION SELECT cod FROM paisagista WHERE empregado.cod = paisagista.cod
UNION SELECT cod FROM gerente WHERE empregado.cod = gerente.cod)